# 2 Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected

Tags: java, spring-security, tomcat7

I have a spring boot application with actuator.  The /health page works when I deploy the application as Embeded web deployment.  But if I create a war file and deploy it in external Tomcat I get prompted for token to access the health page.  Here is my SecurityConfig.java

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable();
    http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/services/courses/**").authenticated();
        .antMatchers("/services/health").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/services/auth/token").permitAll();
    Filter tokenAuthenticationFilter = (Filter) this.tokenAuthenticationFilter;
    http.addFilterBefore(tokenAuthenticationFilter,  UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
}
```

While looking at tomcat log files, I see the following logs in localhost.2016-08-08.log

```
08-Aug-2016 11:58:40.186 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log 2 Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath
08-Aug-2016 11:58:44.928 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
08-Aug-2016 11:59:02.412 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log ContextListener: contextInitialized()
```

I have already added logging.level.org.springframework.web=DEBUG, and -verbose:class to see class loading information.  But so far have not made much progress.

Any idea what else I should try?

Comment: Hmm.., the following url works http://localhost:8080/services/services/health.  I was expecting http://localhost:8080/services/health.  Why are there two services?

Comment: I have the same exact problem.. no luck so far.